# PHP Remote Connection to MS Access 2016 Database

Tags: php, windows, ms-access

I'm working on getting information from a submitted HTML form entered automatically into an Access 2016 database.  My understanding of this process is limited, so I ask that you bear with me.

The HTML form is stored on a 64-Bit Windows Server 2008 R2 DC that is doubling as a Web Server.  PHP has also been installed and configured on this Server.

The database is stored on a separate 64-Bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Virtual Server.

I've seen plenty of articles regarding PHP and SQL (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) but very little about PHP and MS Access.  I understand now that I need to set up an ODBC Connection but that's where I begin to get lost.

Questions:

- Am I correct in thinking the ODBC Connection needs to be set up/configured on the Web Server?
- Am I correct in thinking only the 64-Bit ODBC Driver is required?  (Although I'm pretty confident this is correct, I have this nagging doubt that, because some 32-Bit computers will be accessing the HTML form, there will also be a need to have the 32-Bit ODBC Driver.  It may seem silly but I'd like confirmation with regards to this.)
- Where is the ODBC driver?  I did a search and it brought me to a download for "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable".  Is this what I'm looking for?  (I admit that, unless it's pretty obvious, I tend to feel I'm in the wrong place.  And unless someone can confirm that 'Redistributable' is the same as 'ODBC Driver', I'm inclined to think I'm looking at the wrong thing.)

Thanks for any help!
Eric

Comment: the bitness of remote machines is irrelevant. they're not the ones connecting to the DB, PHP is the one actually connecting. That means you need to use the ODBC DSN appropriate for your PHP - if it's a 32bit php, then you need a 3bit dsn.

Comment: Thank you, Marc.  I thought that might be the case but good to have confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the code running on your web service is x64, then yes of course you will need the x64 Access (ACE) odbc driver.
You are correct in choosing Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable. In fact, you might as well use the 2013 one. Don’t forget to choose the x64 version.

The fact that x32 or x64 computers connect to the web site is not relevant – the server and web code is running as an x64 in process and thus you need to use the x64 odbc driver for Access.

Also while the accDB access file CAN BE on the other server as you point out, that file name MUST be in a folder that that the web server has full rights to. So you not using an IP address, but a FULLY qualified windows path name to a legal windows folder and a legal windows file (in this case the access accDB file). So keep in mind that you do not connect to an Access database, but in fact are opening a windows file. You don’t connect to a word document, you open it. You don’t connect to a PowerPoint file, you open it. And you don’t connect to an Access accDB file, but your software (the odbc driver) will in fact do a DIRECT windows OS file open of the Access file.

So unlike a web site or say SQL server that allows a connection via a socket (tc/ip + a IP address), an Access file is NOT a socket based system, but is in fact a plane jane windows file that will be opened in-process by YOUR software. So the opening of the Access file occurs on the web server – even if that Access accDB simply a USB jump drive plugged into that server, or some other file share on the servers network. We talking about the code on the web server opening that Access file – that Access file thus must be located in a folder that is directly accessible by the web server code running.

Thus you don’t need the ACE data engine installed on that second server for example – only where the code is running do you need the ODBC driver. The significant issue here is that most ODBC drivers allow you to “connect” to some server with a database engine. Because Access is file based then BOTH the ODBC driver and the data engine MUST be installed on the computer that uses the ODBC driver. That driver thus will ALWAYS launch a copy of the data engine local and on the same computer using the ODBC driver. When you use say a SQL driver, you requite a local copy of the SQL database engine – with Access you do!

Comment: Thank you, Albert...your explanation helps me immensely!

Comment: Albert...one more question regarding your answer.

Comment: Albert...sorry but I didn't have time to edit my comment above.  I have a couple more questions regarding your answer.  You mention ODBC Driver as well as data engine.  Yesterday, I had started to think you were saying they are the same thing.  Now I'm realizing that they're two different things.  One is the actual ODBC Driver...and the second thing is the 64-Bit "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" (or 2013 Redistributable).  Both need to be installed on the Web Server...is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Yes, they both ODBC and data engine need to be installed and in fact there is NOT a separate ODBC driver download or install. You only have the choice to install the redistributable  which installs both ODBC drivers and the data engine. There is no ability to install the two parts separate.